# Determine object type of Facebook OpenGraph result

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Objects that can be accessed via FB OpenGraph are listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

But the JSON result doesn't contain a parameter like 'object_type'. Is there a way to determine the object type of any query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but I am trying to understand your question better. In my mind, you know exactly what you are querying for.

If you do this https://graph.facebook.com/me/home for example, the JSON result actually includes type like this:

```
     "type": "link",
     "created_time": "2012-04-13T18:40:59+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-04-13T18:45:33+0000",
     "shares"
```

However if you query using this: https://graph.facebook.com/me/links the JSON result does not include type since you know you will only be getting "links" at this point.

I hope I am answering your question.

Edited:

You can do the following:
http://graph.facebook.com/1234567890?metadata=1

Comment: I want to query https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890 and I _don't_ know what type of object I'm querying.

Comment: oh ok, you can add metadata=1. http://graph.facebook.com/1234567890?metadata=1 for example.. have you tried this?

Comment: Great! Make an answer of your comment, so I can accept it. Thanks